# How to update MongoDB document atomically?

Tags: java, mongodb, transactions, nosql, spring-data

Here's what I'd like to acheieve:

Do the following transaction:

1. Get the current value from the document
2. Run `new_value = update(value)` (let's say it's a Java function)
3. Write new_value to the document

I could use findAndModify() but the problem is that it's kinda limited. It only offers specific methods like min, max, inc etc.

What if I'd like to have some arbitrary function?

Comment: Have you tried using a transaction?

Comment: You can use an aggregation pipeline to update a document. The pipeline can transform the existing document's field/values using the pipeline stages and operators. And, the update operation on a document is _atomic_.  This is an option - and you can avoid writing a "function" for that (Java has methods). See [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html).